# split string in JS by multiple letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of letters and I am trying to cut them into an array using split(), but I want it to split for multiple letters. I got it to work for an individual letter:

```
str = "YFFGRDFDRFFRGGGKBBAKBKBBK";
str.split(/(?<=\R)/); //-> Works for only 'R'
Result->[ 'YFFGR', 'DFDR', 'FFR', 'GGGKBBAKBKBBK' ]
```

What I want:

```
str = "YFFGRDFDRFFRGGGKBBAKBKBBK";
letters =['R', 'K', 'A'];
// split by any of the three letters (R,K,A)
Result->[ 'YFFGR', 'DFDR', 'FFR', 'GGGK', 'BBA', 'K', 'BK', 'BBK' ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "character class" group:  `[RKA]`

Everything you put inside these brackets are alternatives in place of one character.

```js
str = "YFFGRDFDRFFRGGGKBBAKBKBBK";
var result = str.split(/(?<=[RKA])/);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is there any way I could substitute RKA with a variable? For example: str.split(/(?<=[letters])/);

Comment: See [Using a variable in a javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/494046/2181514)  `str = "YFFGRDFDRFFRGGGKBBAKBKBBK"; letters = "RKA"; re = new RegExp("(?<=[" + letters + "])"); str.split(re);`

Answer (score 4):

Beside splitting, you could match non ending characters with a single any character sign.

```js
const
    str = "YFFGRDFDRFFRGGGKBBAKBKBBK",
    result = str.match(/[^RKA]*./g);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass regex in split

```
"YFFGRDFDRFFRGGGKBBAKBKBBK".split(/[RKA]+/);
```

Comment: OP is already passing a regex in the split `str.split(/(?<=\R)/);` - they're trying to find *which* regex will match they're requirement.  Which is: `/(?<=[RKA])/`